# Error al compilar proyecto con UTF-8 en Java

Tags: java, utf-8, netbeans-8.2

Al darle en Clean and Build a un proyecto Java en NetBeans, pero me aparecen estos errores

Los datos con utf-8 se traen de un Web Service Php NuSoap

```
C:\Users\alumno.desarrollo2\Documents\Proyectos Java\Token\build\generated-sources\jax-rpc\META\Petrinovich.java:3: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
// JAX-RPC Standard Implementation (1.1.3, compilaci?n R1)
C:\Users\alumno.desarrollo2\Documents\Proyectos Java\Token\build\generated-sources\jax-rpc\META\PetrinovichPortType.java:3: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
// JAX-RPC Standard Implementation (1.1.3, compilaci?n R1)
C:\Users\alumno.desarrollo2\Documents\Proyectos Java\Token\build\generated-sources\jax-rpc\META\PetrinovichPortType_Stub.java:3: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
// JAX-RPC Standard Implementation (1.1.3, compilaci?n R1)
C:\Users\alumno.desarrollo2\Documents\Proyectos Java\Token\build\generated-sources\jax-rpc\META\PetrinovichPortType_getSolicicitudLicencia_RequestStruct.java:3: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
// JAX-RPC Standard Implementation (1.1.3, compilaci?n R1)
C:\Users\alumno.desarrollo2\Documents\Proyectos Java\Token\build\generated-sources\jax-rpc\META\PetrinovichPortType_getSolicicitudLicencia_RequestStruct_SOAPBuilder.java:3: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
// JAX-RPC Standard Implementation (1.1.3, compilaci?n R1)
C:\Users\alumno.desarrollo2\Documents\Proyectos Java\Token\build\generated-sources\jax-rpc\META\PetrinovichPortType_getSolicicitudLicencia_RequestStruct_SOAPSerializer.java:3: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
// JAX-RPC Standard Implementation (1.1.3, compilaci?n R1)
C:\Users\alumno.desarrollo2\Documents\Proyectos Java\Token\build\generated-sources\jax-rpc\META\PetrinovichPortType_getSolicicitudLicencia_ResponseStruct.java:3: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
// JAX-RPC Standard Implementation (1.1.3, compilaci?n R1)
C:\Users\alumno.desarrollo2\Documents\Proyectos Java\Token\build\generated-sources\jax-rpc\META\PetrinovichPortType_getSolicicitudLicencia_ResponseStruct_SOAPBuilder.java:3: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
// JAX-RPC Standard Implementation (1.1.3, compilaci?n R1)
C:\Users\alumno.desarrollo2\Documents\Proyectos Java\Token\build\generated-sources\jax-rpc\META\PetrinovichPortType_getSolicicitudLicencia_ResponseStruct_SOAPSerializer.java:3: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
// JAX-RPC Standard Implementation (1.1.3, compilaci?n R1)
C:\Users\alumno.desarrollo2\Documents\Proyectos Java\Token\build\generated-sources\jax-rpc\META\Petrinovich_Impl.java:3: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
// JAX-RPC Standard Implementation (1.1.3, compilaci?n R1)
C:\Users\alumno.desarrollo2\Documents\Proyectos Java\Token\build\generated-sources\jax-rpc\META\Petrinovich_SerializerRegistry.java:3: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
// JAX-RPC Standard Implementation (1.1.3, compilaci?n R1)
C:\Users\alumno.desarrollo2\Documents\Proyectos Java\Token\build\generated-sources\jax-rpc\META\Registro.java:3: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
// JAX-RPC Standard Implementation (1.1.3, compilaci?n R1)
C:\Users\alumno.desarrollo2\Documents\Proyectos Java\Token\build\generated-sources\jax-rpc\META\Registro_SOAPBuilder.java:3: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
// JAX-RPC Standard Implementation (1.1.3, compilaci?n R1)
C:\Users\alumno.desarrollo2\Documents\Proyectos Java\Token\build\generated-sources\jax-rpc\META\Registro_SOAPSerializer.java:3: error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
// JAX-RPC Standard Implementation (1.1.3, compilaci?n R1)
14 errors
C:\Users\alumno.desarrollo2\Documents\Proyectos Java\Token\nbproject\build-impl.xml:947: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\alumno.desarrollo2\Documents\Proyectos Java\Token\nbproject\build-impl.xml:270: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 3 seconds)
```

Comment: Los archivos no están en UTF-8, ese es el problema. No sé a qué te refieres con "datos". El problema no son los datos, si no el código fuente. Intenta abrir el archivo donde da el error con netbeans y mira si se ven correctamente los acentos.

Comment: Ya lo solucioné, pasos Click derecho en el proyecto->propiedades->Sources->Seleccionar Encoding "windows-1252"

Comment: @Sagara podrias ayadirlo como respuesta por si alguien mas tiene el mismo problema